# Сайт ЦБ РФ перестал парситься

Tags: python, requests, bs4, useragent

Имеется следующая функция:

```
def get_ruonia():
    url = 'https://cbr.ru/hd_base/ruonia/dynamics/'
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) \
    Chrome/95.0.4638.69 Safari/537.36 Edg/95.0.1020.53'}
    response = rq.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text)
    data = list(soup.find('table', attrs={'class': 'data'}).children)[3].findAll('td', attrs={'class': 'right'})
    ruonia = data[0].text.replace(',', '.')
    return ruonia
```

Данная функция недавно перестала работать из-за того, что сайт цб рф не дает нормально спарсить данные. Как видно я уже пробовал и user-agent подставной использовать. Но все равно никак.

Значение переменной soup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><title>DDOS-GUARD</title><meta charset="utf-8"/><meta content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" name="viewport"/><script>var DOMReady=function(t){var e=document,d="addEventListener";e[d]?e[d]("DOMContentLoaded",t):window.attachEvent("onload",t)},loadScript=function(t,e){var d=document.createElement("script");d.type="text/javascript",d.src=t,"string"==typeof e&&""!==e&&(d.id=e),(document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]||document.body).appendChild(d)};DOMReady(function(){loadScript("https://check.ddos-guard.net/check.js"),loadScript("/.well-known/ddos-guard/check?context=free_splash","ddg_script_f"),setTimeout(function(){document.location.reload(!0)},3e3)});</script><style>*{margin:0;padding:0}body,html{font-family:Open Sans,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;height:100%;background:linear-gradient(to top,#e5f3fb,#fff)}.logo{width:120px;margin-bottom:35px}#title{font-size:32px;font-weight:900;margin-bottom:40px}#description{color:#8f9390;margin-bottom:30px}#link-ddg{white-space:nowrap;margin-bottom:30px;font-size:18px}#link-ddg a:focus:active:hover:visited{color:#00adee}#link-ddg a:active{color:#00adee}#link-ddg a:hover{color:#00adee}#link-ddg a:visited{color:#00adee}.container{display:flex;flex-direction:column;justify-content:center;align-items:center;height:100%;text-align:center;background:url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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) center bottom no-repeat}.lds-spin{width:80px;height:80px}@media screen and (max-width:1200px){.logo{width:100px}#title{font-size:29px}#link-ddg{font-size:15px}#link-ddg{font-size:20px}}@media screen and (max-width:770px){.logo{width:70px;margin-bottom:10px}#title{font-size:15px;margin-bottom:10px}#description{margin-bottom:10px;font-size:13px}#link-ddg{margin-bottom:10px;font-size:13px}.lds-spin{width:40px;height:40px}#link-ddg{font-size:18px}}</style></head><body><div class="container"><div class="logo"><svg id="dl" viewbox="0 0 6.62 7.69" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><defs><style>.cls-1{isolation:isolate}.cls-2{fill:#00adee}.cls-3{fill:#fff}</style></defs><title>ddos_3</title><g class="cls-1" data-name="2560" id="_2560"><g data-name="Gr2" id="G2"><path class="cls-2" d="M3.3,0A6,6,0,0,1,0,1.91C.13,4.46,1.6,7.49,3.3,7.65,5,7.49,6.47,4.46,6.6,1.91A6,6,0,0,1,3.3,0Z"></path><polygon class="cls-3" points="4.55 4.73 4.55 2.74 3.29 1.79 2.03 2.71 2.03 2.91 3.25 2.2 3.25 2.59 2.03 3.16 2.03 3.4 3.25 2.95 3.25 3.26 2.03 3.66 2.03 3.91 3.25 3.66 3.25 4.01 2.03 4.18 2.03 4.43 3.25 4.36 3.25 4.73 1.89 4.73 1.89 5.09 4.71 5.09 4.71 4.73 4.55 4.73"></polygon></g></g></svg></div><div id="title"></div><div id="description"></div><div id="link-ddg"><a href="https://ddos-guard.net" id="link" target="_blank"></a></div><div class="lds"><svg class="lds-spin" height="100px" preserveaspectratio="xMidYMid" style="background: none;" viewbox="0 0 100 100" width="100px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><g transform="translate(80,50)"><g transform="rotate(0)"><circle cx="0" cy="0" fill="#00adee" fill-opacity="1" r="10" transform="scale(0.7525 0.7525)"><animatetransform attributename="transform" begin="-0.875s" dur="1s" keytimes="0;1" repeatcount="indefinite" type="scale" values="0.7 0.7;1 1"></animatetransform><animate attributename="fill-opacity" begin="-0.875s" dur="1s" keytimes="0;1" repeatcount="indefinite" values="1;0"></animate></circle></g></g><g transform="translate(71.21320343559643,71.21320343559643)"><g transform="rotate(45)"><circle cx="0" cy="0" fill="#00adee" fill-opacity="0.875" r="10" transform="scale(0.715 0.715)"><animatetransform attributename="transform" begin="-0.75s" dur="1s" keytimes="0;1" repeatcount="indefinite" type="scale" values="0.7 0.7;1 1"></animatetransform><animate attributename="fill-opacity" begin="-0.75s" dur="1s" keytimes="0;1" repeatcount="indefinite" values="1;0"></animate></circle></g></g><g transform="translate(50,80)"><g transform="rotate(90)"><circle cx="0" cy="0" fill="#00adee" fill-opacity="0.75" r="10" transform="scale(0.9775 0.9775)"><animatetransform attributename="transform" begin="-0.625s" dur="1s" keytimes="0;1" repeatcount="indefinite" type="scale" values="0.7 0.7;1 1"></animatetransform><animate attributename="fill-opacity" begin="-0.625s" dur="1s" keytimes="0;1" repeatcount="indefinite" values="1;0"></animate></circle></g></g><g transform="translate(28.786796564403577,71.21320343559643)"><g transform="rotate(135)"><circle cx="0" cy="0" fill="#00adee" fill-opacity="0.625" r="10" transform="scale(0.94 0.94)"><animatetransform attributename="transform" begin="-0.5s" dur="1s" keytimes="0;1" repeatcount="indefinite" type="scale" values="0.7 0.7;1 1"></animatetransform><animate attributename="fill-opacity" begin="-0.5s" dur="1s" keytimes="0;1" repeatcount="indefinite" values="1;0"></animate></circle></g></g><g transform="translate(20,50.00000000000001)"><g transform="rotate(180)"><circle cx="0" cy="0" fill="#00adee" fill-opacity="0.5" r="10" transform="scale(0.9025 0.9025)"><animatetransform attributename="transform" begin="-0.375s" dur="1s" keytimes="0;1" repeatcount="indefinite" type="scale" values="0.7 0.7;1 1"></animatetransform><animate attributename="fill-opacity" begin="-0.375s" dur="1s" keytimes="0;1" repeatcount="indefinite" values="1;0"></animate></circle></g></g><g transform="translate(28.78679656440357,28.786796564403577)"><g transform="rotate(225)"><circle cx="0" cy="0" fill="#00adee" fill-opacity="0.375" r="10" transform="scale(0.865 0.865)"><animatetransform attributename="transform" begin="-0.25s" dur="1s" keytimes="0;1" repeatcount="indefinite" type="scale" values="0.7 0.7;1 1"></animatetransform><animate attributename="fill-opacity" begin="-0.25s" dur="1s" keytimes="0;1" repeatcount="indefinite" values="1;0"></animate></circle></g></g><g transform="translate(49.99999999999999,20)"><g transform="rotate(270)"><circle cx="0" cy="0" fill="#00adee" fill-opacity="0.25" r="10" transform="scale(0.8275 0.8275)"><animatetransform attributename="transform" begin="-0.125s" dur="1s" keytimes="0;1" repeatcount="indefinite" type="scale" values="0.7 0.7;1 1"></animatetransform><animate attributename="fill-opacity" begin="-0.125s" dur="1s" keytimes="0;1" repeatcount="indefinite" values="1;0"></animate></circle></g></g><g transform="translate(71.21320343559643,28.78679656440357)"><g transform="rotate(315)"><circle cx="0" cy="0" fill="#00adee" fill-opacity="0.125" r="10" transform="scale(0.79 0.79)"><animatetransform attributename="transform" begin="0s" dur="1s" keytimes="0;1" repeatcount="indefinite" type="scale" values="0.7 0.7;1 1"></animatetransform><animate attributename="fill-opacity" begin="0s" dur="1s" keytimes="0;1" repeatcount="indefinite" values="1;0"></animate></circle></g></g></svg></div></div><script type="text/javascript">var lang=navigator.language,host=window.location.hostname;"ru"==lang||"ru-RU"==lang?(document.getElementById("title").innerHTML="Проверка браузера перед переходом на сайт "+host,document.getElementById("description").innerHTML="Это автоматический процесс. Вы будете перенаправлены на запрашиваемый ресурс в ближайшее время.<br>Пожалуйста ожидайте...",document.getElementById("link").innerHTML="Защита от DDoS-атак DDoS-GUARD"):(document.getElementById("title").innerHTML="Checking your browser accessing "+host,document.getElementById("description").innerHTML="This process is automatic. Your browser will redirect to your requested content shortly.<br>Please allow up to 5 seconds...",document.getElementById("link").innerHTML="DDoS protection by DDoS-GUARD");</script></body></html>
```

Как исправить это и как спарсить данные в таком случае?

Comment: Они защиту от ddos включили и без выполнения того JS кода который виден в этом ответе ничего не выйдет. А тех данных, что вы парсите в официальном API нет ? https://cbr.ru/development/ Для api не должно быть подобных защит.

Comment: Просто российские официальные  сайты немного взгруснули. Скорее всего этот код скоро не то что не будет работать, а будет просто ненужен.

Comment: Спасибо за интересные мысли. Нет в api нету данных по RUONIA, по крайней мере я не нашел. А что значит без выполнения того JS кода? Это мне его как-то нужно заранить и тогда меня пропустит?